# Stripping off punctuation from list of strings

Tags: python, list, strip

I have a list of words like this

```
['Hey', 'yo', 'Hey?', 'Yeah.', 'john:']
```

I would like to remove `, . " ' ? ! *` and everything else that is at the beginning or end

```
for element in array:
    # perform
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Note that `str` is an *immutable* type: you cannot *remove* anything from the strings themselves. You can only change the list, or create a new one. With new strings.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you mean by 'everything else.'

```
[elt.strip(',."\'?!*:') for elt in array]
```

is pretty easy and gets the job done, assuming you have a reasonably-small list of removable tokens.

```
In [1]: ar = ['Hey', 'yo', 'Hey?', 'Yeah.', 'john:']

In [2]: [elt.strip(',."\'?!*:') for elt in ar]
Out[2]: ['Hey', 'yo', 'Hey', 'Yeah', 'john']
```

Or, as suggested:

```
import string
[elt.strip(string.punctuation) for elt in ar]
```

Otherwise, if you want to remove *everything* else that isn't ~alphanumeric, you could do:

```
import re
[re.sub(r'\W+', '', elt) for elt in array]
```

which will remove all non-word (to be precise, `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) characters.

Comment: I think the OP means `string.punctuation`